# How Display The Data on Page Load

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I've been working on the Search CRUD using Google WebApp Script via watching a YouTube tutorial, I'm almost done but I'm stuck in a place I couldn't figure out to sort the issue.

I want to load the search field and the data on first page load. but based on this code I need to click on the Search Tab and then get the search field to find the data. How do I get rid of the Search Tab and get straight into the search bar and data.

On Page load
[image]

Second Occurrence (After the Click)
[image]

My code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
　　　
   <style>
   .nav-link {
   cursor: pointer;
   }
   </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="container">
    
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  
  <li class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-link"id="search-link">Search</div>
  </li>

</ul>

     <div id="app"></div>    
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
  <script>
  
  var data;
  
  function loadView(options){
var id = typeof options.id === "undefined" ? "app" : options.id;
var cb = typeof options.callback === "undefined" ? function(){} : options.callback;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html){
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = html;
typeof options.params === "undefined" ? cb() : cb(options.params);
})[options.func]();
}

function setDataForSearch(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned){
data = dataReturned.slice();
}).getDataForSearch();
}

function search(){

var searchinput = document.getElementById("searchinput").value.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
var searchWords = searchinput.split(/\s+/);
var searchColumns = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

// and or

var resultsArray = data.filter(function(r){

return searchWords.every(function(word){
return searchColumns.some(function(colIndex){
return r[colIndex].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) !== -1
});

});

});
var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("searchResults");
var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
var template = templateBox.content;

searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";

resultsArray.forEach(function(r){

var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
var hinmokuColumn = tr.querySelector(".hinmoku");
var buhinCodeuColumn = tr.querySelector(".buhinCode");
var buhinNameColumn = tr.querySelector(".buhinName");
var hitsuyoColumn = tr.querySelector(".hitsuyo");
var genkaColumn = tr.querySelector(".genka");
var kobaiColumn = tr.querySelector(".kobai");
var sagakuColumn = tr.querySelector(".sagaku");
var kenshoColumn = tr.querySelector(".kensho");

hinmokuColumn.textContent = r[0];
buhinCodeuColumn.textContent = r[1];
buhinNameColumn.textContent = r[2];
hitsuyoColumn.textContent = r[3];
genkaColumn.textContent = r[4];
kobaiColumn.textContent = r[5];
sagakuColumn.textContent = r[6];
kenshoColumn.textContent = r[7];

searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);

});
}

function loadSearchView(){
loadView({func:"loadSearchView", callback: setDataForSearch});
}


document.getElementById("search-link").addEventListener("click",loadSearchView);


function inputEventHandler(e){
if (e.target.matches("#searchinput")){
  search();
}
}
document.getElementById("app").addEventListener("input",inputEventHandler);
    
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Server Side Code

```
function getDataForSearch(){
    
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Array");
  
  return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow(),8).getValues();

}
```

I need to type letters in order to data display.
Screen Shot 3
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- There are some actions that are currently happening when the `Search tab` is clicked.
- You want these actions to happen when the page loads.

#### Solution:

In the HTML you provided, there's a `click` event listener attached to the `Search tab` you mention (`id="search-link"`):

```
document.getElementById("search-link").addEventListener("click",loadSearchView);
```

This means the function `loadSearchView` is gonna execute when the `Search tab` is clicked.

If I understand you correctly, you want `loadSearchView` to execute when the page loads. In that case, you could just add the following event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("load", loadSearchView);
```

#### Notes:

- Since you didn't provide server-side code, I cannot know whether `loadSearchView` will do what you intend it to do. This solution just makes sure `loadSearchView` is executed when the page loads.
- If you want to get rid of the `Search tab`, just remove it from your HTML (`<div class="nav-link"id="search-link">Search</div>` and its container elements).

#### Reference:

- [Window: load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: It Worked :) @lamblichus. I've added the server side function in the original post.

Comment: I need one more assistance, I need to display the data without I type in the search field, at the moment, The data is displayed only if i type in the search field, I failed after many test and trials, Can you hint where I should make the change?

Comment: I'm too looking forward to a solution.

Comment: @Miyer I'm not sure what data are you talking about. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Miyer From what I can see, the returned data depends on what input is written to the search field. Therefore, if nothing is written, what data should be returned?

Comment: @Miyer Also, please consider that this was not part of the original question, so I'd suggest you to post a new question for that.

Comment: @Iamblichus I've added the screenshot on the bottom of the original post, No data is displayed unless I type something, I want to display the data as page loads.

Comment: @Iamblichus I stated in my post "How do I get rid of the Search Tab and get straight into the search bar and data" I think I was not clear with my question :( sorry for causing inconvenience.